# Slight crackling sensation apparently due to the chain sticking to the cassette teeth

Tags: chain, gears, sram

I've just assembled my bike, so it has hardly been ridden (less than 200km) and all the components are new.

Everything works perfectly, except an unpleasant very slight crackling sensation when I pedal gently on a smooth road.

I think I've identified that the problem comes from the chain, whose links come out of the cassette teeth in an abrupt way, these mini jumps are then felt in the crankset and the pedal.

On this video, you can see these little jumps. They're not very obvious, but you can clearly feel them when riding the bike or turning the pedal with the hand when giving some resistance to the wheel.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkYIk.jpg

I have checked my two other bikes, these little jumps on the cassette and this crackling sensation in the pedal are present, but reduced to a point that you cannot feel them with your feet while pedaling.

Since it's a 1x transmission, I thought maybe it's a chain line problem, but no : it happens even on well aligned cogs, the worst being the 5th (out of 11).

So, my question : is is a known problem that has a solution, e.g. tweaking a screw, cutting the chain's length ? Or is it just that my standards for chain smoothness are too high, maybe incompatible with 1x transmissions ?

---

Here are the specifications of the bike.

It's a gravel with SRAM 1x transmission. The components are standard as far as I know, you can find this setup on commercial bikes.

Cassette: SRAMPG 1130 11v

Derailleur: SRAM Rival 1 long type 3

Crankset: SRAMRival 1 GXP 11v

Chain: SRAMPC-1130 11V

Edit : I've checked the chain, it's as advertised a 11 speed, according to the "11s" mark ok the power lock.

For a moment I thought it was the dirt, but no, after a complete wash it's no better.

Comment: Can you verify from the markings on the chain and cassette that you have the parts that you think you to. What you are describing could be the result of using a chain that is too wide, such as using a 10 speed chain on an 11 speed drivetrain.

Comment: I had this on my Ultegra R8000 11 speed. The teeth were just slightly too aggressively bent towards the next cog to help with shifting. After a few thousand kilometers (-> second chain) they were worn far enough and it went away.

Comment: @michael thanks for the advice, i'll see how it goes through the kilometers

Comment: Actually, it's because the way you're riding scares the bike, so it's teeth are chattering.

Comment: @Michael that's an answer not a comment.  Remember comment upvotes don't award rep.

Comment: @Maelito that's a very clean chain - have you lubricated it after the cleaning?   A lack of lube might exacerbate the symptom

Comment: Yes it's well lubricated. I can try to add some more and clean the excess though.

Comment: I've had similar issues on a bike when the derailleur dropout was not properly aligned. It doesn't seem like that would be consistent with your issue being the worst in middle gears though.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check how the dérailleur is fixed, what angle, etc.

Comment: What is the frame spacing/axle type? Chainstay length? Is the hanger aligned? Does the problem persist as you tweak the cable tension back and fourth? Is it getting better in the lower gears?